# How to get number of unread gmail emails, not unread conversations

Tags: android, gmail

I need to get 10 pushed emails using gmail android app. I start sending 10 emails and force android sync to check inbox. After that I get notification about incoming mail. How can I get the number of incoming emails, [gmail API](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html) provides only NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS not the number of unread emails in conversation. Maybe there is another way to query gmail content resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found possible solution, this worked for me:
[turn off message threading](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/disable_turn_off_message_threading_conversation_view_google_gmail.html)

---

Now NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS flag gives me the number of unread emails